# Clearing textbox for multiple forms from a Class

Tags: vb.net, class, controls

I have created a class to handle clearing the textboxes and other controls when I click the clear button I created. My current project has only one from, frmMain. What I want to be able to do is set the class so it can clear the controls from which ever form calls the class. How can I set up my class to recognize which form is calling it? I am working in VB.net, but I can translate from C# if I need to.

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    Dim iClear As New ClearForm
    iClear.ClearTextBoxes()
End Sub


Public Class ClearForm
Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(Optional ByVal ctlcol As Control.ControlCollection = Nothing)
    If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = frmMain.Controls
    For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
        If TypeOf (ctl) Is ComboBox Then
            DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).Text = Nothing
        Else
            If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = frmMain.Controls
    For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
        If TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(ctl, TextBox).Clear()
        Else
            If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = frmMain.Controls
    For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
        If TypeOf (ctl) Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox).Checked = False
        Else
            If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Add a constructor to ClearForm that accepts a form reference, i.e. `Public Sub New(ByRef FormToClear As Form)` and use that reference to access its controls, and clear them. Alternatively, you could pass that same reference to the ClearTextBoxes() sub

Comment: It's right there in your method parameter... iClear.ClearTextBoxes(frmMain.Controls)  will clear your frmMain, so just add the other form in as a parameter...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It appears I've been going in the wrong direction.This helps point me where I need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the general idea down, but you're missing a reference to a form and also iterating over the controls collection many more times than necessary. My take on this would be to make the class able to accept either a form reference or collection of controls, and then execute a single recursive loop rather than several:

```
Public Class ClearForm

    Private _Controls As Control.ControlCollection = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByRef ControlCollection As Control.ControlCollection)
        Me._Controls = ControlCollection
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef FormToClear As Form)
        Me._Controls = FormToClear.Controls
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearControls()
        RecursiveClearControls(Me._Controls)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RecursiveClearControls(ctlCol As Control.ControlCollection)
        If ctlCol IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctlCol.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ctl As Control In ctlCol
                If TypeOf (ctl) Is ComboBox Then
                    DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).Text = Nothing
                ElseIf TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox Then
                    DirectCast(ctl, TextBox).Clear()
                ElseIf TypeOf (ctl) Is CheckBox Then
                    DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    If ctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                        RecursiveClearControls(ctl.Controls)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This way, you can instantiate a new class with either a form reference or a control collection, and then just call `ClearControls()`. When called, it starts a private recursive loop that will iterate the controls just once. Also, passing ByRef instead of ByVal helps a bit with efficiency.

Comment: I noticed as I was stepping through the code it went through each of the controls twice. That also threw me off. This is great. Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Soo says - add a New constructor and a property so you can reference it. Although the ClearTextBoxes could be optimised a little, I have left alone as it works for you.. Hope this helps.. :)

```
Public Class ClearForm
    Private m_FormToClear As frmMain
    Public Property FormToClear As frmMain
        Get
            Return m_FormToClear
        End Get
        Set(value As frmMain)
            m_FormToClear = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(frm As frmMain)
        m_FormToClear = frm
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(Optional ByVal ctlcol As Control.ControlCollection = Nothing)
        If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = m_FormToClear.Controls
        For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
            If TypeOf (ctl) Is ComboBox Then
                DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).Text = Nothing
            Else
                If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                    ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = m_FormToClear.Controls
        For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
            If TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox Then
                DirectCast(ctl, TextBox).Clear()
            Else
                If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                    ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If ctlcol Is Nothing Then ctlcol = m_FormToClear.Controls
        For Each ctl As Control In ctlcol
            If TypeOf (ctl) Is CheckBox Then
                DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox).Checked = False
            Else
                If Not ctl.Controls Is Nothing OrElse ctl.Controls.Count <> 0 Then
                    ClearTextBoxes(ctl.Controls)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

And then call using..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CF As ClearForm = New ClearForm(Me) 
    CF.ClearTextBoxes()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use the shorter initialization technique: `Dim CF As New ClearForm(Me)` rather of the long one that you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to create base class which will know what form it belong too

```
Public MustInherit Class ClearControlsForm 
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Protected Sub ClearControls()
        ClearControls(Me.Controls)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub ClearControls(controls As Control.ControlCollection)
        For Each textbox In controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            textbox.Text = String.Empty
        Next

        For Each checkBox In controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
            checkBox.Checked = False
        Next
        ' ... clear other controls types
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then all new forms inherits from `ClearControlsForm` and you can use `ClearControls` method from base class

```
Public Class MyAnotherForm
    Inherits MyNamespace.ClearControlsForm 

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        ClearControls() // Will clear current form's controls
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you make `ClearControls` method overridable you will be able to customize it's behaviour in the derived class.

With this approach you will keep Form related logic in the form classes, which will be easy to maintain.